# How format character Y-m to month in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a variable date like "2019-2" and "2019-10". I need to plot a graph in ggplot, however, when creating a graph with the date "2019-10" is seen first than "2019-2". How can I fix it?
I tried to do the following:

```
as.Date("2019-2",format="%Y-%m")
as.Date("2019-10",format="%Y-%m")
```

However, it shows NA.

Comment: Convert to a date via as.Date("2019-2-01",format="%Y-%m-%d"), i.e. add "-01" as day. Then use scale_x_date with date_labels = "%Y-%m"

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use `sprintf()` with the numeric format for month to add the leading zero.

```
yr_month <- c("2020-1","2020-2","2020-10")

sprintf("%4d-%02d",as.numeric(substr(yr_month,1,4)),as.numeric(substr(yr_month,6,7)))
```

...and the output:

```
> sprintf("%4d-%02d",as.numeric(substr(yr_month,1,4)),as.numeric(substr(yr_month,6,7)))
[1] "2020-01" "2020-02" "2020-10"
>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to artificially add a day value in to parse e.g. "2019-10" as a `Date` object. Assuming you have your dates in some vector `dates`, there's a bunch of options for that.

Base R:

```
format(as.Date(paste0(dates, "-01")), "%Y-%m")
```

With the `lubridate` pakage:

```
format(lubridate::parse_date_time(dates, "ym"), "%Y-%m")
```

However, `format` turns your `Date` object into a `character` object. If you think you'll need date-like behavior in the future, you could convert your `dates` to `POSIXct` objects instead...

```
as.POSIXct(paste0(dates, "-01"))
```

...and let `ggplot` deal with formatting them as "year-month" by adding the following to your plot (assuming the date will be on the x-axis):

```
ggplot(...) +
  ... +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%Y-%m")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding day to your day and then use `format`:

```
format(as.Date("2019-2-1",format="%Y-%m-%d"),"%Y-%m")

"2019-02"

format(as.Date("2019-10-1",format="%Y-%m-%d"),"%Y-%m")

"2019-10"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can represent year and month without day using the yearmon class and `scale_x_yearmon()` avoiding the need to convert to Date class. See `?scale_x_yearmon` for additional arguments. Here we will use the defaults.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

# test data
dd <- data.frame(x = 1:2, Date = as.yearmon(c("2019-2", "2019-10")))

ggplot(dd, aes(Date, x)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_yearmon()
```

Alternately transform the yearmon column to Date class by using  `as.Date` to give a date representing the first day of the month.

```
dd$Date <- as.Date(dd$Date) # convert from yearmon to Date class
```